# Is it possible to add more commands to the Texstudio tikz panel?

Tags: texstudio

Texstudio has quite useful panels for entering Tikz, PSTricks, Metapost and Asymptote commands automatically without typing them. The set of tikz commands are very limited though. I was wondering if there is a way to edit the st of available commands and if there is a way to add additional panels (for instance, for pgfplots) to the available panels